# PowerShell: Restrict variable values

Tags: powershell

I have the following variable:

```
$UPNSuffixChange = $True
```

In my script there's an if statement that will only run if this is true:

```
If ($UPNSuffixChange) {}
```

The idea being that the variable can be set to `$False` resulting in this section being skipped.

How can I restrict the value of this variable to only `$True` or `$False` to avoid mistyped values?

Comment: Who or what will assign the variable, though? Consider making `$UPNSuffixChange` a `[switch]` parameter of a function or the script as a whole, so passing the correct value is simple and natural. [Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff677563) are much friendlier than loose scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but there are multiple variables like this at the top of the script. I want it to fail right at the beginning should one of the variables not be set to either true or false rather than waiting until they get to the script section each one's responsible for and failing at that point instead. These variable are simply turning different sections on and off as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strongly-type it is as a `boolean`:

```
[bool]$UPNSuffixChange = $True
```

---

If an attempt is made assign anything other than `$true`/`$false` (or the equivalents `1`/`0`) to this variable, PowerShell will through the following error:

> Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean
>   parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True,
>   $False, 1 or 0.

I used a `System.String` as an example; it is the same for other types.

Comment: When it says "numbers" it really does mean "numbers": `$UPNSuffixChange = 33.4` is legal (and assigns `$True`). `[switch] $UPNSuffixChange = $true` is more restrictive and will really only allow `$False` and `$True`. (Although whether you should use switch parameters like that is debatable.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Good point, I forget that `0 = $false`, `non-0 = $true` is also a thing in PowerShell. I think the `[switch]` type matches OP's stated specs perfectly - consider posting as answer so I can upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. [bool] works fine for this instance as will be a variable that other users of the script will set. I want this to error should they enter anything other than $true or $false for this variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the SWITCH type.
Switch can only be $true or $false.
It is default $false.

```
[switch]$var = $true

if($var){
    "Var is TRUE"
}
If(!$var){
    "Var is FALSE"
}
```